# linux how can i be sure what conf file service is using?

Tags: linux

Hello im using Ubuntu and for example i installed nginx via apt-get and via [passenger](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu), now i have two nginx.conf location (/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) (but i removed first nginx installation with `apt-get remove nginx`) where i can ensure what configuration file (nginx.conf) /etc/init.d/nginx start will use ? It si more general linux question than nginx related.

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/init.d/nginx

Comment: ah thank you, there is constant `DAEMON=/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx` so it will be using `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` i guess

Comment: Doesn't `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` do the job? This should show _all_ open descriptors (including the conf file's) as well as their names after the `->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to rename one of these configuration files and see whether the service can still start.

Comment: good idea, but i have some errors in both config therefore i need to ensure what config is using but in log i can see it too.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Debian-based Linux, you can use `dpkg` to find the package to which a file belongs:

```
dpkg -S /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Note that this will only work for files installed by `dpkg` (and therefore `apt-get`, Synaptic, USC, etc.).  In this particular case, I'd wager that passenger installs into /opt, since an alternate package manager installing into /etc would be borderline evil.